# How to pass Default date and time values into stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure, In which I am passing the column values according to Null or Not Null. I have set default value `getdate()` to column 'datetime' and set it to not null. But while passing the values to its columns I don't know what value i need to pass to 'datetime' column as it will store default values.

here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insert_test2]
    (@testid int, 
     @age int, 
     @salary decimal, 
     @name varchar(250),
     @datetime datetime = default,
     @gender bit) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO test2 
    VALUES (@testid, @age, @salary, @name, @datetime, @gender)
END
```

I want to know what should I pass in @datetime :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way is to use `COALESCE`

```
INSERT INTO test2 (testid,age,salaray,name,[datetime],gender)
VALUES (@testid, @age, @salary, @name, coalesce(@datetime,getdate()), @gender)
```

Or based on value of `@datetime` parameter you need to frame Insert query. Remove `datetime` column from insert and select list when it is `NULL` so the default value will be populated

```
If @datetime is null
    INSERT INTO test2 (testid,age,salaray,name,gender)
    VALUES (@testid, @age, @salary, @name, @gender)
Else 
    INSERT INTO test2 (testid,age,salaray,name,[datetime],gender)
    VALUES (@testid, @age, @salary, @name, @datetime, @gender)
```

You can also think about altering the procedure to accept `table type` as input so that you can insert more than one record at a time

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable post. I have corrected it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insert_test2]
    (
      @testid int, 
      @age int,
      @salary decimal,
      @name varchar(250),
      @gender bit
    ) 
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
insert into test2 (testid,age,salary,name,gender) values (@testid,@age,@salary,@name,@gender)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

To set default value as current date when date is not supplied to stored procedure.

Below is the answer.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insert_test2]
        (@testid int, 
         @age int, 
         @salary decimal, 
         @name varchar(250),
         @datetime datetime = NULL,
         @gender bit) 
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO test2 
        VALUES (@testid, @age, @salary, @name, ISNULL(@datetime, GETDATE()), @gender)
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not pass the @datetime variable at all. I have used the example provided earlier.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insert_test2]
    (@testid int, 
     @age int, 
     @salary decimal, 
     @name varchar(250),
     @gender bit) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO test2 
    VALUES (@testid, @age, @salary, @name, GETDATE(),@gender)
END
```

Please note you may modify GETDATE() function as per your requirement by using CONVERT keyword and various available formats.